# ExternalInterface & zooming, oh my!

Tags: apache-flex

In my application, I have a call to an externalinterface to open a separate browser in a new window:

As you can see, I open a separate browser w/ width of 700 and height of 500. Now, if we interact w/ that popup window and zoom in and/or zoom out everything is fine. You close the popup & close out of the main application. All fine until now.

The problem happens when you relaunch the application and click the popup window. If, during your last visit you zoomed in on the popup, this time around that same popup will be much smaller than the 700 width & 500 height that is set. Has anyone experienced this? What's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible for you to set the `zoom` CSS property on the dollywood.com page? I leverage YUI's `reset-fonts-grids.css` to normalise all element defaults, including page zoom level. Perhaps this could help?

If poss chuckus a link so I/we can replicate the prob?

EDIT:

Re: my comment below, if you need a more complicated JavaScript solution which handles things like a user resizing the window, if that also triggers the above prob, then also link to/include:

http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.1/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js

...and then in the `<head>` element of your app's document, add something like this:

```
var ye = YAHOO.util.Event;
ye.on(window, 'load', function(e){

    fixZoom();

    // safe to manipulate the DOM now
    ye.on(window, 'resize', function(e){

        fixZoom();

    });

});

function fixZoom(){
    // Do any extra zoom fixing stuff here
}
```

Comment: Absolutely, if you only want to use it to normalise page elements like above then simply copy or link to http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.1/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css in your app's document. I point you toward 2.8.1 because I'm familiar with it, YUI3 is available and awesome, so I hear :)